# Google chrome does not apply font-face to parts of text

Tags: google-chrome, css, font-face

I'm using CSS3 `@font-face` for web fonts, page looks fine in Firefox and IE but it does not show defined font in parts of texts, I don't know why it happens:
Highlighted text:
[image: highlighted text]

It's HTML output:
[image: highlighted text]
Another friend tested it with chrome, it was same. it's page url :http://milan-group.ir/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out `&nbsp;` caused this problem.